# How to retrieve rowid if column is named rowid?

Tags: oracle

Let's say I have the following table:

```
CREATE or replace TABLE t (id INT, content STRING, rowid INT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (42, 'hello', 5), (43, 'world', 5);
```

How would I get both the `rowid` pseudocolumn as well as the `rowid` actual column in the db?

For example, doing something like:

```
select id, content, rowid, ?rowid-pseudocolumn?
from t;
```

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm

Also, in general, if there is a 'shadow column', is there any procedure to retrieve that if there is the same-named user column?

Comment: That create table statement is not Oracle syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any illegal keyword used as an object identifier or illegal characters within an object identifier can be made to work if surrounded in *double-quotes*, but `ROWID` in all-caps won't be permitted. You can, however, make it lowercase:

```
create table t (id integer, content varchar2(50),"rowid" rowid); -- if storing actual ROWIDs, otherwise use integer datatype 

select id,content,"rowid",rowid from t; -- shows stored rowid col and the real rowid separately
```

But be advised that storing rowids as permanent column values is generally a very bad idea, so this isn't something that should come up often, if at all. And, if there was a legit case for doing this, it would be far better to simply rename the column to avoid having to treat it differently (e.g. `ROW_ID`, or if just a number unrelated to Oracle's rowids, something entirely different to avoid confusion).

Answer (score 1):

You should get an Invalid identifier error or similar reserved word error when trying to build such a table.

Comment: Yes, generally speaking. Though, see what Paul said in his answer.